# Is getting free discovery calls from coaches without having an intention to purchase OK?

Tags: ethics, promotion, coaching

I like getting coaching sessions. I find a place some coaches are offering 1 hour free coaching. Till now, I got plenty of free coaching from different coaches. I know these coaching calls are kind of promotion and introduction. Is getting free service be evaluated ethical or abuse?
In some messages I wrote I love getting coaching calls and interested only free calls. Then I didn't get responses.

What might be the best approach for asking interested in free coaching without abusing?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't illegal behavior - but I do find it very scummy. If you know from the outset that you have no intention of purchasing a product, then accepting a free sample is fundamentally dishonest.

A Free sample is designed to give a prospective client a sample, in the hopes of convincing them to spend money.
You've already predetermined that you aren't going to spend the money so you have violated that part of the implicit social contract.

And yes - if I was offering a free sample and you said you only wanted the free sample - I wouldn't waste my time on you either.

Comment: Grabbing the loss leader and running away is a common behavior. It's even figured into the decision to try that marketing approach; the company knows many folks won't buy, but hopes that enough do to make this worth the attempt, and some who were planning not to buy might be convinced after having a taste. I wouldn't make a habit of it on a product I really had no interest in, especially one where the sample costs them a significant amount (eg real human time), but for something smaller... it's a judgement call.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask. If they know you aren't interested in buying, they have no interest in spending time on you.

There's nothing illegal about signing up for a free trial and then not buying, though you're quickly going to run out of how much value you can extract that way. Whether it's ethical is something you have to decide.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious moral situation here and I would like you to put yourself in the position of the person giving the 'free' coaching.

Most work or lifestyle coaches are self employed individuals who are trying to generate new business from genuine new clients who desire a long term partnership to help improve their life skills, prospects or achieve a greater balance between work and life.

Their generous offer of a one hour free session to a ligger who has no intention of taking out ANY coaching contract is a complete waste of their time and yes, it is immoral and unfair. Fine maybe if it is a large firm where the coach is salaried but as I said, if most coaches are self employed, you are effectively 'stealing their lunch'.

It is hard enough for self-employed people to win new clients without encountering an immoral serial scumbag like you. You admit to having done this more than once too which makes you a complete piece of dirt.

No wonder you need coaching but in reality, you need a firm kick in the groin for being so unthinking and selfish. Whatever do you actually do for a living?